# error when i run flutter build in terminal

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I try to run `flutter build apk --release` in terminal to output my apk but it shows `e: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table` error in terminal here's all command in terminal:

````dart
 Building with sound null safety 

Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Newfolder\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 29 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Newfolder\Sdk\platforms\android-29
"Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)" finished.
e: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     304.8s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (18.1MB).```
````

Comment: Run `flutter doctor` in your terminal once and then post the output

Comment: I run but it says no issues

Comment: May I know what you are exactly trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command: `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use IntelliJ IDEA because it's a really great coding software. It has loads of function and there's a button: Build->Flutter->Build APK